# Split 1 Column into 2 Columns in a Dataframe

Tags: r, split, strsplit

Here's my data frame.

```
    > data
       Manufacturers  
1   Audi,RS5  
2   BMW,M3  
3   Cadillac,CTS-V  
4   Lexus,ISF
```

So I would want to split the manufacturers and the models, like this,

```
    > data
    Manufacturers       Models
1   Audi                RS5  
2   BMW                 M3  
3   Cadillac            CTS-V  
4   Lexus               ISF
```

I would appreciate any help on this question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If I google your title, second hit leads to strsplit, which is what you're after, I think.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, in this case, I would think "`read.csv`" would suffice: `read.csv(text = as.character(data$Manufacturers), header = FALSE)`. Don't know if that is any more efficient than `strsplit`.

Comment: This would work as well: 
`library(qdap); colsplit2df(data,, c("Manufacturer", "Model"), ",")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some sample data. You could use a character vector, but I'll use a data frame to match your example:

```
df <- data.frame(Manufacturers = c("Ducati,Diavel", "Honda,Goldwing",
                                   "BMW,R1200GS", "Harley-Davidson,Fat Boy"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Use strsplit() to separate the strings. Note that it requires a character (not a factor) vector. Strsplit() returns a list object:

```
list <- strsplit(df$Manufacturers, ",")
```

Transform the list into a data frame and set appropriate column names:

```
library("plyr")
df <- ldply(list)
colnames(df) <- c("Manufacturer", "Model")
```